Probability Generating Functions for Coin Flip Problems?
I am trying to understand the concept of "Hitting Time Distributions" in Probability.
Example 1: In the first example, consider a case where there is a coin that has a $p_1$ probability of Heads. We need to find out the probability distribution for the number of flips required to get 100 heads (i.e. not 100 heads consecutively, just 100 heads).
Suppose I call the time required to observe 100 heads for the first time as the Hitting Time. To me, it seems that I might be solvable using the Negative Binomial Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution):
$$P(X = k) = \binom{k-1}{r-1} p_1^r (1 - p_1)^{k-r}$$
$$P(X \leq n) = \sum_{k=r}^n \binom{k-1}{r-1} p_1^r (1 - p_1)^{k-r}$$
The Negative Binomial Distribution describes the number of trials before the first failure. Logically, I can treat the 100th head as a "failure". Therefore, I can modify these equations for my problem.
Example 2: In the second problem, suppose we have the same coin - but now we are interested in finding out the probability distribution for the number of flips needed to get 5 consecutive heads. Here, I call the number of flips needed to get 5 consecutive heads for the first time as the Hitting Time.
At first I thought that the Negative Binomial Distribution can also be used for this problem, but I am unsure how to modify the Negative Binomial Distribution to suit this problem.
Doing some readings, I found out that these types of problems are quite popular and are often solved using methods such as First Step Analysis (e.g. First Step Analysis of a Markov Chain process). By writing a linear system of equations based on a Discrete Time Markov Chain, we can find out the Expected Value for the number of flips needed for 5 consecutive heads:
$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 - p_1 & p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 - p_1 & 0 & p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 - p_1 & 0 & 0 & p_1 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 - p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_1 & 0 \\
   1 - p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$
$$
   E_5 = 0 \quad (\text{ absorbing state})
    $$
$$
   E_0 = 1 + (1 - p_1) E_0 + p_1 E_1
    $$
$$
   E_1 = 1 + (1 - p_1) E_0 + p_1 E_2
$$
$$
   E_2 = 1 + (1 - p_1) E_0 + p_1 E_3
$$
$$
   E_3 = 1 + (1 - p_1) E_0 + p_1 E_4
$$
$$
   E_4 = 1 + (1 - p_1) E_0
 $$
But this only tells us the expected number of flips. How do I find out the probability distribution for this number?
Reading some other questions (e.g. Generating function for the hitting time of a Markov chain. , Markov Chain Question using probability generating function, Method of Generating function - Markov Chain , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSNlxH22ln8), it seems like this can be solved using Probability Generating Functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function), but I am not sure how to do this.
I tried to set up similar equations as First Step Analysis using Probability Generating Functions:
$$ G_i(z) = \sum_{j \in S} p_{ij} z^j $$
$$
   G_0(z) = z + p_1 z G_1(z) + (1 - p_1) z G_0(z)
$$
$$
   G_1(z) = z + p_1 z G_2(z) + (1 - p_1) z G_0(z)
$$
$$
   G_2(z) = z + p_1 z G_3(z) + (1 - p_1) z G_0(z)
$$
$$
   G_3(z) = z + p_1 z G_4(z) + (1 - p_1) z G_0(z)
$$
$$
   G_4(z) = z + p_1 z G_5(z) + (1 - p_1) z G_0(z)
$$
$$
   G_5(z) = z
   $$
$$
   \begin{pmatrix}
   G_0(z) \\
   G_1(z) \\
   G_2(z) \\
   G_3(z) \\
   G_4(z)
   \end{pmatrix}
   =
   \begin{pmatrix}
   z \\
   z \\
   z \\
   z \\
   z + p_1 z^2
   \end{pmatrix}
   +
   \begin{pmatrix}
   (1 - p_1) z & p_1 z & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   (1 - p_1) z & 0 & p_1 z & 0 & 0 \\
   (1 - p_1) z & 0 & 0 & p_1 z & 0 \\
   (1 - p_1) z & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_1 z \\
   (1 - p_1) z & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
   G_0(z) \\
   G_1(z) \\
   G_2(z) \\
   G_3(z) \\
   G_4(z)
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
$$G_0(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(T = n) z^n$$
But I think I have done everything incorrectly and feel lost. I am not sure how this will all lead to a Probability Distribution Function for the Hitting Time.
Can someone please show me how I can correctly use Probability Generating Function to derive the Probability Distribution Function in this question?

Note: Follow Up Question Relationship Between Cramer's Rule and Probability Functions?


You don't state this in your question but I assume $G_i(z)$ is the pgf for the hitting time conditioned on having just flipped exactly $i$ heads. As a sanity check, pgfs always need to satisfy $G(1) = 1$ (since this is the sum of the probabilities) so your initial $z$ terms don't belong there.
First step analysis says the following here. I will rewrite your $p_1$ as $p$ since no $p_2$ appears anywhere. The next flip is either heads or tails. If it's heads, we've flipped $i + 1$ heads, so the pgf of the possible results is $z G_{i+1}(z)$. If it's tails, we need to start all over, so the pgf of the possible results is $z G_0(z)$. If we've already flipped $5$ heads then we're done, so $G_5(z) = 1$. This gives a corrected system of equations
$$G_0(z) = pz G_1(z) + (1 - p) z G_0(z)$$
$$G_1(z) = pz G_2(z) + (1 - p) z G_0(z)$$
$$G_2(z) = pz G_3(z) + (1 - p) z G_0(z)$$
$$G_3(z) = pz G_4(z) + (1 - p) z G_0(z)$$
$$G_4(z) = pz + (1 - p) z G_0(z).$$
As a sanity check, plugging in $G_i(1) = 1$ doesn't reveal any issues, and as a second sanity check, the expected value is given by $E_i = G_i'(1)$ and computing the derivative at $z = 1$ on both sides gives your previous system of equations for the expected values (to simplify the calculation note that multiplying by $z$ has the effect of increasing the expected value by $1$).
Now we convert to matrix form:
$$\begin{bmatrix} G_0(z) \\ G_1(z) \\ G_2(z) \\ G_3(z) \\ G_4(z) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ zp \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} z(1 - p) & zp & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ z(1 - p) & 0 & zp & 0 & 0  \\ z(1 - p) & 0 & 0 & zp & 0  \\ z(1 - p) & 0 & 0 & 0 & zp \\ z(1 - p) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} G_0(z) \\ G_1(z) \\ G_2(z) \\ G_3(z) \\ G_4(z) \end{bmatrix}$$
and writing $G(z)$ for the entire column vector of pgfs this gives
$$\left( 1 - z P \right) G(z) = zv$$
where
$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - p & p & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 - p & 0 & p & 0 & 0 \\ 1 - p & 0 & 0 & p & 0  \\ 1 - p & 0 & 0 & 0 & p \\ 1 - p & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, v = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ p \end{bmatrix}$$
do not depend on $z$ but only on $p$. This in turn gives
$$\boxed{ G(z) = (1 - zP)^{-1} zv = \left( \sum_{k \ge 0} z^{k+1} P^k \right) v }.$$
Depending on what you want to do from here you can compute this inverse using Cramer's rule and/or try to find an explicit closed form for the powers of $P$, I don't think it should be so bad either way.

@ Qiaochu Yuan : thank you so much for your answer!

some questions I had here:


In the end, how can G(z) be used to find out the PMF of absorption times?



What will taking the inverse of G(z) lead to?


thank you so much!

@konofoso: 1) $G(z)$ is, by definition, the vector whose components are the pgfs $G_i(z)$. The hitting time pgf is $G_0(z)$ so it's the first component of this vector. 2) By "this inverse" above I meant the inverse of $1 - zP$. This inverse is a matrix (whose entries will be rational functions in $z$) and multiplying this matrix by $v$ gives $G(z)$, as stated above.

thank you so much! I have accepted your answer as the official answer! if you have time, you can please expand on this? I am trying to use Cramer's Rule myself ... I will post my progress soon

Is a power series expansion needed here at all?

@konofoso: Well, $G_0(z)$ is a power series, so... yes?

Sorry, I misworded that. Thank you so much for everything ... I am trying to sort all of this out ... hope to hear from you soon ... thanks once again ... much appreciated !

@ Qiaochu : I placed a bounty on this question - if you have time, can you please expand a bit on your answer? Maybe apply cramer's rule, take some derivatives and show the pdf of the final hitting time distribution?

@konofoso: I suggest asking this as a separate question instead.

I have posted this as a new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4945961/relationship-between-cramers-rule-and-probability-functions
